# How to get PullRequest ID to get description in Azure DevOps?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-yaml

The code works smoothly, however I cannot retrieve the `System.PullRequest.PullRequestId` automatically. Azure DevOps is returning me an error.

```
| The term 'System.PullRequest.PullRequestId' is not recognized as a name
| of a cmdlet, function, script file, or executable program. Check the
| spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is
| correct and try again.
```

My code:

```
- task: PowerShell@2
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |

      # Call the Azure DevOps Services Rest API.
      $url = "$($env:SYSTEM_TEAMFOUNDATIONCOLLECTIONURI)$env:SYSTEM_TEAMPROJECTID/_apis/git/repositories/$(Build.Repository.ID)/pullRequests/$(System.PullRequest.PullRequestId)?api-version=7.0"
      $headers = @{
        Authorization = "Bearer $(System.AccessToken)"
      }
      $pullRequestInfo = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Method 'GET' -ContentType 'application/json' -Headers $headers

      # Get PR title and description from the json response.
      $json = $($pullRequestInfo | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 100 | ConvertFrom-Json)
      $description = $json.description
      $title = $json.title
```

I did a test, if I add manually the pullRequestId, works, I can have access to pull request description. Example:

```
$url = "$($env:SYSTEM_TEAMFOUNDATIONCOLLECTIONURI)$env:SYSTEM_TEAMPROJECTID/_apis/git/repositories/$(Build.Repository.ID)/pullRequests/10315?api-version=7.0"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`System.PullRequest.PullRequestId` is available only on validation builds. If you run a build manually or as a CI process, `System.PullRequest.PullRequestId` is not available. Add your build to the branch policies: [Build validation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/branch-policies?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser#build-validation).